Azure Synapse Apache Spark Pools: .gz package added but notebook run error says not found
I have notebooks that contain r code. On their own, they work fine when run manually. To schedule and automate these workbooks, we have to use pipelines to call the r notebooks. However, pipelines don't allow inline install of the r library packages. So, we have to install those packages on the Apache spark pool. I was able to do this successfully for all of the packages and their dependencies. I’ve run into a problem with the HydroVuR.gz package (This also happens to be our 1 custom package. hmmm??). While I have been able to add all of the packages to the Apache Spark Pool, when I  run the notebook, I get an error specific to only our Hydrovu package.
You can see below that the HydroVuR.tar.gz package is there on the SparkPool. However, I get a HydroVu specific error when I try to call it.

Since these packages are installed onto the pool and no longer Inline… I comment out the install.packages lines and just run the libraries

[1] "Error in library(HydroVuR): there is no package called ‘HydroVuR’"

The STDOUT when I installed it on the pool looks like it was successful?

Is something wrong with my HydroVuR.tar.gz package? Why can't the pool see it?
Dependency packages and versions (Downloaded from CRAN):



Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

I think I found the problem. My .tar.gz package had no version number. Once I added HydroVuR_0.0.0.9000.tar.gz to the file name of the package, I was able to install it and see it. Then, I was able to run my pipeline to success. I think the problem is now solved. Thanks for your help Dileep.

Error:

[1] "Error in library(HydroVuR): there is no package called
‘HydroVuR’"

As you mentioned you are getting ERROR when using the
Install_github("ROSSSyndicate/HydroVuR")
Install HydroVuR from GitHub using devtools
Devtools::install_github("ROSSSyndicate/HydroVuR")

I have tried the below approach:
install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("jvandens/HydroVuR")

Results:


packageVersion("HydroVuR")

‘0.0.0.9000’

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpbueDIx/downloaded_packages’
Downloading GitHub repo jvandens/HydroVuR@HEAD
cpp11 (0.4.7 -> 0.5.0) [CRAN]
curl  (5.2.1 -> 5.2.2) [CRAN]
httr2 (1.0.2 -> 1.0.3) [CRAN]
Installing 3 packages: cpp11, curl, httr2
Installing packages into ‘/nfs4/R/user-lib/application_1726032047530_0001’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/cpp11_0.5.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 275693 bytes (269 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 269 KB

library(HydroVuR)
sessionInfo()



Reference: jvandens/HydroVuR

Hi Dileep, It isn't inline package install that I need help with. Azure synapse notebooks and pipelines do not allow inline package install. The packages have to be installed on the apache spark pool instead. So, I can't use "install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("jvandens/HydroVuR")"
My problem is that eventhough I installed the package on the sparkpool, when I go to run the library, sparkr can't see that it was installed on the pool.

cpp11 (0.4.7 -> 0.5.0) [CRAN]
curl  (5.2.1 -> 5.2.2) [CRAN]
httr2 (1.0.2 -> 1.0.3) [CRAN]
@CFCJBJohn can you confirm if you want to install the above dependecies from HydroVuR pacakge?

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

Dileep, I installed all of the dependencies and a few more suggested and I still have the same problem. While the repository installs on the pool to success, it still doesn’t show when I run the list all packages command. I have confirmed several times that I can install the package successfully via inline install. The package installs and works as expected and I can see it in the list session packages command.

Can you provide the list of dependencies with their versions?

https://github.com/rossyndicate/HydroVuR/blob/main/DESCRIPTION but I got the .tar.gz packages from CRAN https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/available_packages_by_name.html
Imports:
dplyr,
httr2,
lubridate,
magrittr,
purrr
Suggests:
rmarkdown,
knitr,
ggplot2

Dileep, I added screen captures of the package versions above in the original post.

@CFCJBJohn sure, let me try it for you and update the solution.

I think I found the problem. My .tar.gz package had no version number. Once I added HydroVuR_0.0.0.9000.tar.gz to the file name of the package, I was able to install it and see it. Then, I was able to run my pipeline to success. I think the problem is now solved. Thanks for your help Dileep.
